# Deploying to Meteor Galaxy

Tags: meteor

I have two Galaxy accounts, and I am attempting to deploy my app with a different account than is "saved" within my OS X terminal.

Can anyone tell me how to specify which account I would like to deploy to?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with the --owner  flag. Always happen to figure it out the moment I reach out for help!

Thanks anyway, people!